# Adding text in a new line in WPF RichTextBox at runtime

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, newline

I want to add some text in a WPF RichTextBox at runtime in a new line.
I can do this using:

```
FlowDocument mcFlowDoc = new FlowDocument();
mcFlowDoc = richTextBox.Document;
Paragraph pr = new Paragraph();
pr.Inlines.Add(status);
mcFlowDoc.Blocks.Add(pr);
StatusText.Document = mcFlowDoc;
```

But there is too much of a gap between two lines.  How can I fix this?

Comment: BTW, there's no point of creating a new `FlowDocument` (`mcFlowDoc = new FlowDocument();`) when you're changing its reference the next line `mcFlowDoc = richTextBox.Document;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation, Paragraph spacing is defined by margins, which do not accumulate (no doubling up), so Julien Lebosquain's answer is correct.

[MSDN on FlowDocument Paragraph Spacing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749187.aspx)

Answer (score 9):

To avoid having to manually set the margin for every paragraph, you can add this to the RichTextBox's XAML:

```
<RichTextBox>
  <RichTextBox.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Paragraph}">
      <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
    </Style>
  </RichTextBox.Resources>
</RichTextBox>
```

Comment: can you give an example of how you setup xaml for a Rich Text Box block or document ? (I'm just getting started with Rich Text Box programming from c#)

Answer (score 7):

Try `pr.Margin = new Thickness(0.0)` to remove the gaps between paragraphs.