# flowdocument - inserting rich text at end creating extra paragraph breaks above insertion point

Tags: wpf, vb.net, flowdocument, richtext

I am creating a flowdocument that consists of multiple records. Each record contains two tables at the top, and then some rich text that I'm pulling out of a database. The code that appends the rich text is found below (cp.Comments contains the rtf tagged text).

```
Dim tr As TextRange
Dim arr() As Byte

Using ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream
  arr = (New System.Text.UTF8Encoding).GetBytes(cp.Comments)
  ms.Write(arr, 0, arr.Length)
  ms.Seek(0, IO.SeekOrigin.Begin)

  tr = New TextRange(fd.ContentEnd, fd.ContentEnd)   'add to end
  tr.Load(ms, DataFormats.Rtf)
End Using
```

The flowdocument renders the first of the records correctly, but all subsequent records are rendered with a break between the first and the second table.  What is the most odd is that I'm rendering the 2 tables *before* importing the RTF, but the RTF is somehow affecting the spacing between the tables anyway.

```
fd = new FlowDocument

for each cp in SomeCollection

   fdtemp = New FlowDocument

   CreateFirstTable(cp, fdtemp)
   CreateSecondTable(cp, fdtemp)
   AddRTF(cp, fdtemp)

   FlowDocumentUtils.AddDocument(fdtemp, fd)

next
```

The problem isn't something related to the data in the first element of the collection - if I tell the rendering to skip the rendering of the first record, then the second record renders ok, but the rest contain the extra spacing.

Note: the problem is definitely related to the rich text insertion - if I comment out the AddRTF call, then all the tables are correctly rendered smashed together. (table margins are all set to (0,0,0,0))

Has anyone ever seen this?

Comment: Have you inspected the raw text of the FlowDocument?

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out the solutions from this other question:

- [Adding text in a new line in WPF RichTextBox at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078824/adding-text-in-a-new-line-in-wpf-richtextbox-at-runtime)

Also, it appears that you have two separate methods:

```
CreateFirstTable(cp, fdtemp)
CreateSecondTable(cp, fdtemp)
```

I suspect that the difference between how these two methods are operating is where the problem is, but w/out knowing what they're really doing, I can only speculate.